# How can I filter nested List with mongodb aggregations in Java code?

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I try to convert mongoAggregation (below) into Java Code. As a result I want to get List of Items (not List of Documents, I know how to achieve it). There is a lot of info about how to create mongo aggregation and so little how to create aggregation with java.

Goal is: to filter prices inside Item so that:

- validFor.isEmpty OR validFor.endDateTime.isAfter(new Date())
- filter alterations so that final price >= 110.

As example we have JSON (below) and expected result to get alteration1 and alteration3

Json:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "prices": [
    {
      "priceName": "price1",
      "validFor": {},
      "alterations": [
        {
          "alterationName": "alteration1",
          "finalPrice": 110
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "priceName": "price2",
      "validFor": {
        "endtDateTime": "2024-10-31T12:00:00Z" //String
      },
      "alterations": [
        {
          "alterationName": "alteration2",
          "finalPrice": 105
        },
        {
          "alterationName": "alteration3",
          "finalPrice": 115
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

MongoQuery:

```
[
    {
    $project: {
      id: 1,
      prices: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$prices",
          as: "price",
          cond: {
            $or: [
              {$eq: ["$$price.validFor", {}]},
              {$gt: [
                  {$dateFromString: {
                      dateString:
                        "$$price.validFor.startDateTime",
                      format:
                        "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z" }}
                  new Date() ]}]}}}}
  },
  {
    $project: {
      id: 1,
      prices: {
        $map: {
          input: "$prices",
          as: "price",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$price",
              {
                alterations: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$$price.alterations",
                    as: "alteration",
                    cond: {
                      $gte: [
                        "$$alteration.finalPrice",
                        110 ]}}}}]}}}}}]
```

My Aggregation (I am stacked on comparing endDateTime: String with new Date())

```
aggregationOperations.add(Aggregation.project()
    .and(
    when(
        new Criteria()
        .orOperator(
            new Criteria("price.validFor").is(new Document()),
            new Criteria("price.validFor.endDateTime")
                .gt(new Date().toString())))
    .then(true)
    .otherwise(false))
    .as("prices"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way how to do it with when-then-else, but this seems like a valid option to filter nested array:

```js
AggregationOperation unwindPrices = Aggregation.unwind("prices");

AggregationOperation match = Aggregation.match(
  Criteria.where("_id").in(variantIds)
  .orOperator(
    Criteria.where("prices.validFor").is(new Document()),
    Criteria.where("prices.validFor.endDateTime")
    .gt("2023-09-14T13:00:00.000Z")
  )
);

AggregationOperation project = Aggregation.project("id", "prices");

AggregationOperation group = Aggregation.group("id")
  .push("prices").as("prices");

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
  unwindPrices,
  match,
  project,
  group
);
```